# How should I increment a number for a round robin threading scenario with least contention?

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked

If many threads are calling `GetNextNumber` simultaneously with the following code, `GetNextNumber` will return 1 more times than any other numbers.

```
private class RoundRobbinNumber
{
    private int _maxNumbers = 10;
    private int _lastNumber;

    private RoundRobbinNumber(int maxNumbers)
    {
        _maxNumbers = maxNumbers;
    }

    public int GetNextNumber()
    {
        int nextNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref _lastNumber);
        if (_lastNumber > _maxNumbers)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lastNumber, 1, _maxNumbers);
            nextNumber = 1;
        }
        return nextNumber;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reset the `_lastNumber` back to one, and reliably return an incremented number for each thread calling `GetNextNumber()`, without having to use a lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to do the operation in a loop until it is successful. I provide a general template for this approach in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736006/158779).

```
public int GetNextNumber()
{
  int initial, computed;
  do
  {
    initial = _lastNumber;
    computed = initial + 1;
    computed = computed > _maxNumbers ? computed = 1 : computed;
  } 
  while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lastNumber, computed, initial) != initial);
  return computed;
}
```

Comment: hmmm...that same method is used in the msdn example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583.aspx  ...But, there is a comment that states: "The Add method, introduced in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, provides a more convenient way to accumulate thread-safe running totals for integers."  So, I just wanted to be sure I'm not missing something.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @EricDahlvang - You're not asking for a running total... That makes all the difference.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but I would prefer a lock() any time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yeah, me too, but since the OP asked for "least contention" solution I figured it was worth posting.

Comment: @EricDahlvang: The problem is that `Interlocked.Add` does not do the rollover logic. You'd still have to a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) in a loop to get the value set correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Andrey's answer without conditional statements:

```
using System;
namespace Utils
{
    public class RoundRobinCounter
    {
        private int _max;
        private int _currentNumber = 0;

        public RoundRobinCounter(int max)
        {
            _max = max;
        }

        public int GetNext()
        {
            uint nextNumber = unchecked((uint)System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentNumber));
            int result = (int)(nextNumber % _max);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O6rO6N) running this code.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if if helps anyone but this could be even simpler:

```
class RoundRobinNumber
{
    private int _maxNumbers = 10;
    private int _lastNumber = 0;

    public RoundRobinNumber(int maxNumbers)
    {
        _maxNumbers = maxNumbers;
    }

    public int GetNextNumber()
    {
        int nextNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref _lastNumber);

        int result = nextNumber % _maxNumbers;  

        return result >= 0 ? result : -result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can do this `return (nextNumber < 0 ? (nextNumber + int.MaxValue + 1) : nextNumber) % _length;`

Comment: `_lastNumber` will eventually overflow after `Int32.MaxValue` calls?

Comment: @ChrisFulstow, yes but Interlocked.Increment will start from int.MinValue (it will not throw)

Answer (score 1):

Usually round-robin is used to select an item from a collection. Based on Alex's answer I made a `RoundRobinCollection` variant.

```cs
public class RoundRobinCollection<T>
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<T> _collection;
    private int _currentNumber = -1;

    public RoundRobinCollection(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _collection = new List<T>(enumerable).AsReadOnly();

        if (!_collection.Any())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use empty collection for RoundRobinCollection.");
        }
    }

    public T GetNext()
    {
        var index = GetNextIndex();
        return _collection[index];
    }

    private int GetNextIndex()
    {
        // This increments the currentNumber in a Thread-safe way, and deals with exceeding int.MaxValue properly
        var nextNumber = unchecked((uint)Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentNumber));
        return (int)(nextNumber % _collection.Count);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```cs
public class SomeClient
{
    private readonly RoundRobinCollection<ServerConfig> _serverConfigs;

    public SomeClient(List<ServerConfig> serverConfigs)
    {
        _serverConfigs = new RoundRobinCollection<ServerConfig>(serverConfigs);
    }

    public void DoSomething(){
       var serverConfig = _serverConfigs.GetNext();
       // Do something with current serverConfig
    }
}
```